# How to stop JBoss EAP 6.0.1

Tags: java, jboss

I start JBoss using the standalone.bat file but I can't seem to find the file to shut it down. I Googled some options and they said run the shutdown file but there is none in my folder.

Comment: THE WORST CASE : Ctrl+ALT+SUP  + ALL JAVA APPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press ctrl-C in the command prompt where you ran standalone.bat from.